# How to rewrite loop to collection functions in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have loop, that iterates collection and find object, that has status = 1, after remove that.

How to rewrite this code on collections functions in Laravel?

```
$announcements->every(function ($value) use ($announcements) {
            foreach($value->offers as $k => $v) {
                if ($v->status == 1) {
                    unset($value->offers[$k]->publisher);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [every() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-every)  checks if all items in the collection return true. You should use [each() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each) instead, to loop through all items and check them individually.

Also if you want to remove some items from the collection, you can use [filter() method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-filter):

```
$fitlered = $announcements->filter(function($value) {
    return $value->status !== 1;
});
```